pivot_longer across multiple columns and type: Can't combine <datetime<UTC>> and <double>
I'm trying to pivot_longer across multiple columns with multiple types. They have a common prefix and I need to keep the value after the underscore.
Reprex data:
dat <- structure(list(id = c(230.1234, 235.1234, 236.1234, 237.1234, 
262.1234, 263.1234, 290.1234, 291.1234, 301.1234, 322.1234, 323.1234, 
342.1234, 356.1234, 363.1234, 364.1234, 430.1234), a1_date = structure(c(1694995200, 
1695254400, 1695081600, 1695081600, 1699488000, 1700611200, 1701043200, 
1701216000, 1701216000, 1710201600, 1710201600, 1710892800, 1710892800, 
1712707200, 1712707200, 1719187200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), a2_date = structure(c(NA, 1696896000, 1698624000, 
1698796800, 1702339200, 1704240000, 1704412800, 1704672000, 1705363200, 
1713830400, 1713916800, 1714435200, 1714953600, 1716336000, 1717372800, 
1722384000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    a1_x = c(142.4434, 147.0534, 142.2234, 141.2934, 148.7234, 
    150.9034, 154.7934, 153.5634, 153.5534, 148.3134, 160.5934, 
    162.8734, 157.3034, 151.9134, 154.9334, 157.6334), a2_x = c(145.6834, 
    150.3334, 137.3134, 152.0934, 163.5034, 154.5134, 158.6834, 
    160.7234, 159.0834, 155.0434, 167.2834, 163.5534, 163.2234, 
    158.0634, 161.6634, 160.0734), a1_z = c(114.9234, 118.9834, 
    115.4534, 115.8534, 114.8634, 117.3234, 116.9834, 117.0934, 
    117.1234, 116.2734, 116.9434, 117.7334, 116.1734, 117.0834, 
    117.0934, 117.0034), a2_z = c(116.6334, 117.9334, 116.8034, 
    117.4434, 115.5534, 117.3434, 117.8734, 118.2134, 118.2534, 
    118.0134, 118.6234, 118.6034, 119.2334, 119.2734, 118.7134, 
    116.4534)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

Which looks like this:
> head(dat)
        id    a1_date    a2_date     a1_x     a2_x     a1_z     a2_z
1 230.1234 2023-09-18       <NA> 142.4434 145.6834 114.9234 116.6334
2 235.1234 2023-09-21 2023-10-10 147.0534 150.3334 118.9834 117.9334
3 236.1234 2023-09-19 2023-10-30 142.2234 137.3134 115.4534 116.8034
4 237.1234 2023-09-19 2023-11-01 141.2934 152.0934 115.8534 117.4434
5 262.1234 2023-11-09 2023-12-12 148.7234 163.5034 114.8634 115.5534
6 263.1234 2023-11-22 2024-01-03 150.9034 154.5134 117.3234 117.3434

I want something that looks like this, where timepoint is derived from the number before the underscore and the new variable names are after the underscore.

How I do pivot across all three columns here, with 2 different data types: date, x, and z?
It looks like the question here has a similar issue, but I can't seem to adjust my code to make it work: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/vsske3/help_with_pivot_longer_for_multiple_repeating/

Try dat |> pivot_longer(-id, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("timepoint", ".value"))

add names_prefix="a" to @lroha answer to remove the leading 'a'
